# How to get current cursor position in vim visual mode

Tags: vim

Is is possible to get current cursor position (line and column) when text is highlighted in any (block, line) visual mode, like statusline `%l` and `%c` do?

Example:

```
function! SomeFunc()
    let l:position = getpos('.')
    echo l:position
endfunction

noremap <F2> :call SomeFunc()<CR>
```

I’ve tested `getpos()` (as in example), `getcurpos()`, `col()`, `virtcol()`, `winsaveview()`, but if I hit `<F2>` in visual mode function does not show the real cursor position but 0 (or 1, depends which function).

Statusline `%l` and `%c` show them. I'm mostly interested how to get numeric values. I'm aware that some workarounds like marks are possible to achieve.
Any idea?

Comment: `getpos()` works okay in Visual mode. Your problem is that you're not in Visual mode anymore.

Comment: Yeap, I've noticed that. Is it possible to "stay" in Visual mode if I'm in the body of a function?

Comment: `:h :map-expression` or `:h :map-cmd` etc. Anything that does not switch the modes, as the "colon" does.